# Most idiomatic way of declaring a deck in Rust

Tags: beginner, rust, playing-cards

I'm new at Rust and I'm trying to implement a cards' deck on Rust, I'm trying to use most idiomatic code I can, but since I'm new at this language, I'd like to hear advice from more experienced programmers. There's my code.
(P.D: Thanks in advance! :>)

```rust
use std::fmt;

use rand::seq::SliceRandom;
use rand::thread_rng;

#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub struct Card<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    value: i8,
    suit: char,
}

impl<'a> fmt::Debug for Card<'a> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{} of {}", self.name, self.suit)
    }
}

pub struct Deck<'a> {
    pub cards: Vec<Card<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Deck<'a> {
    const SUITS: [char; 4] = ['♥', '♦', '♣', '♠'];
    const CARDS: [(&'a str, i8); 13] = [
        ("ACE", 11),
        ("TWO", 2),
        ("THREE", 3),
        ("FOUR", 4),
        ("FIVE", 5),
        ("SIX", 6),
        ("SEVEN", 7),
        ("EIGHT", 8),
        ("NINE", 9),
        ("TEN", 10),
        ("JACK", 10),
        ("QUEEN", 10),
        ("KING", 10),
    ];

    pub fn new() -> Deck<'a> {
        let mut deck: Vec<Card> = Vec::new();

        for suit in Deck::SUITS.iter() {
            for (card_name, card_value) in Deck::CARDS.iter() {
                deck.push(Card {
                    name: card_name,
                    value: *card_value,
                    suit: *suit,
                });
            }
        }
        let mut rng = thread_rng();
        deck.shuffle(&mut rng);

        Deck { cards: deck }
    }

    pub fn deal_card(&mut self) -> Card<'a> {
        if self.cards.is_empty() {
            self.initialize_deck()
        }
        self.cards.pop().unwrap()
    }

    pub fn get_initial_cards(&mut self) -> Vec<Card> {
        vec![self.deal_card(), self.deal_card()]
    }
    /// When the cards vector is empty, shuffle a new deck
    fn initialize_deck(&mut self) {
        *self = Deck::new();
    }
}
```

*EDIT:* This module is meaned to be used with a BlackJack game, that is the reason because the cards have those particular values

Comment: If you're only going to use a constant once, why not just inline it?  That makes it clearer that it's only for a single purpose.  Declaring it separately implies you're going to reuse it.

And rather than storing the name on the card, it would be more memory efficient to implement a function to look up the name based on the value.

Comment: The constants are there because I want the user to be able to see the cards and suits that I'm using on the deck. I want them to be what in other languages you'd call static variables. 
About storing both name and value, you're totally right, but I think that for readibility, I'm going to delete the value, and create the function that gives the value according to the name. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You’ve made a fairly classic mistake when it comes to modeling cards in software. Cards have different values depending on the game. In some games, an Ace == 1, others 11, sometimes it could be either *in the same game* (Blackjack for example). Non-face cards aren’t always their value either. In some games, they’re all “5 points”, regardless of the number on the card.

In short, the value of a particular card depends on the game, not the card. How might you redesign to account for that?

Comment: Another example: in the "Belote" (a French game), both the strength and the points of a card depend on if the suit is trump or not. Before the players chose the trumps suit, the cards do not have those characteristics fixed.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm going to use this module with a BlackJack game I'm developing, that is the reason because the cards have those particular values